# difference while adding static libraries in make file

Tags: makefile, static-libraries

**my question is i am confused while adding a static library in my makefile which one is correct both the styles are giving different outputs and seems like correct one is 2nd style and how?**

```
ABS_LIB= -L/home/saravind/work/Pinnacle_DEVIMPT_Sprint26/GeoPlugins/AtlasSegmentationPlugin/AbsEngine/lib/SunOS -lAbsInterface

my_unittest :   Image_unittest.o  gtest-all.o gtest_main.o
    $(CXX)   $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(ABS_LIB) $^ -o $@
```

and

```
my_unittest :   Image_unittest.o  gtest-all.o gtest_main.o
$(CXX)   $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS)  $^ -o $@   $(ABS_LIB)
```

Answer (score 1):

The second one is correct, because the `-l` options must be at the end of the `gcc` command line.

By the way, instead of using the custom `ABS_LIB` variable, you may want to use the `LDLIBS` and `LDFLAGS` make variables.

Comment: Specifically listed libraries are searched *once* at the time they are listed on the command line. So they need to come *after* the object files that use their symbols.